# In what ways, if any, did Avengers: Age of Ultron foreshadow Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, avengers-age-of-ultron, foreshadowing

*Avengers: Endgame* is quite packed with references to other movies. But I rewatched *Avengers: Age of Ultron* a little while ago and I realized that at least Tony Stark's vision (given to him by Wanda Maximoff) seemed to be a direct foreshadowing of the destruction of Thanos entering the universe in the third act of *Endgame*. What other, if any, scenes or references in *Ultron* foreshadow events in *Endgame*?

Comment: "That up there... That's the endgame..."

Comment: This "if any" is a good addition. Maybe better question would be how little idea did Marvel had about ending of this story arc, back then - very little I'm afraid. That there's gonna be Avengers, Guardians, Thanos and Stones and probably not much more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Age of Ultron is the opening act for the running theme of conflict between Cap and Stark, which is theoretically the reason why Endgame became necessary. After all, the tragic flaw of the Avengers is that their egos get in the way of what they could accomplish together. This results in them losing people, and finding humility. Eventually they overcome their problems and work together in Endgame, to at least correct their biggest mistake.

That theme exists in miniature within Age of Ultron. Tony and Bruce want to march forward, Cap wants to be more careful. They don't work together, and many people die. Including half of the twins, a direct parallel to the Thanos snap. While this is more of a thematic reference than a direct one, I think it is why these two movies are tied together as bookends of the story.

Comment: Hawkeye: Cap, what do you name your shield? Captain America: I name mine Sue. What do you name yours? Hawkeye: Quicksilver.

Comment: It's funny because it's true...

Comment: Haha, totally. I feel bad for the actor, he didn't get much of a chance in the MCU, and then couldn't even get a sniff of Wandavision.